# How to permanently configure DNS servers on VMware ESXi 7 via SSH?

Tags: ssh, dns, vmware, esxi

I want to change (replace) the default DNS servers (which are `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`) on VMware ESXi 7.0u1 (specifically custom ISO for Fujitsu servers downloaded from official VMware servers) via SSH shell. Actually, I want to use it in `%firstboot` section of my Kickstart file.

I tried to run the following commands, which work but only until I reboot the server. Then the DNS servers are reset to the default ones.

```sh
esxcli network ip dns server remove -a
esxcli network ip dns server add -s "$dns"
```

Is there anything else I need to run to make the change permanent?

Answer (score 0):

From your SSH connection you should be able to use "dcui" command and modify your DNS without losing your configuration after a reboot.

Comment: Running `dcui` over SSH does not output anything and returns `1`. The DCUI service is enabled (actually I test this on fresh VMware ESXi 7.0u1 installation). I searched the Internet for a solution, I coudn’t find one. However, as I understand it, `dcui` is TUI utility I get when I access the server directly (KVM), which is not what I what, as I want to configure the server programatically (i.e. without any user intervention).